# Why from dialog is always opened at the beginning of fullCalendar when I want it opened when click calendar event triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I try t modify an example from full calendar. It showed *an alert* when *click event* triggered. I change to open a form by adding a form and load it on *click event*.

I don't understand why *form dialog* is opened before calendar rendered.

It should be open after *click (or select) event* triggered by calendar.
The code below is quite straight forward.

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrpaLmyd/) and below is the code.

Do I miss smth? many thanks for any advice.

```
<head>
    ... skipped some imports

    <style>
        ... skipped some css and styles

    </style>

    <script>
        var dialog;
      
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                selectable: true,

                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },

                dateClick: function (info) {
                    // alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
                   info.jsEvent.preventDefault();

                   dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 400,
                        width: 350,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Create an account": (),
                            Cancel: function() {
                                dialog.dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        },

                        close: function() {
                            form[ 0 ].reset();
                            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        }
                    });
                },

                select: function (info) {
                    alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
                }
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
    <form>
      .... skipped all textbox
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you've added your addEvenListener to trigger when DOMContentLoaded happens and as I understand that, it loads the calendar when the DOM loads.

Comment: yes, it is what I expect to happen. But it is not. A dialog is opened instead of calendar. you can try it on attached fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize dialog at start of the code, not only in `dateClick` event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": (),
            Cancel: function() {
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
            }
        },

        close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        selectable: true,

        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },

        dateClick: function (info) {
            // alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
            dialog.dialog("open");
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
        },

        select: function (info) {
            alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
        }
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: hi @samuel , have you try the code above and running? Cause it still loads the form instead of the calendar.. you can try it on my [fiddle][https://jsfiddle.net/361q75z9/2/].. or simply you can share your fiddle than i learn from it..

Comment: Oh, you just forgot to import the jquery and jquery ui cdn. :)

Comment: Remember to import jQuery before any other cdn. And jQuery UI is needed for `$().dialog` function.

Comment: Hi @samuel, https://jsfiddle.net/2q854mvp/2/ -> i have added jQuery and jQuery.UI , Could you show me what I have missed? feel free to edit it until it runs..

Comment: @slawalata Your fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/2q854mvp/2/ contains several errors, did you look at the console? That's why you see a plain dialog and no calendar - none of your JavaScript is running. There are 2 syntax errors, and also you've tried to load a CSS file which doesn't exist

Comment: @ADyson, many thanks :) I didn't see that. I have removed the line that causes the errors and form dialog shown... BUT it has a transparant bg T__T but it is a different problem and discussion i think :) I am still open for suggestion to solve that *LAUGH* many thanx AD and SA

Comment: @slawalata yes it would be a good idea to open a new question about that, as it's a separate issue. Perhaps you have some CSS missing or something.